# How could Thor become a part of Earth's mythology despite he didn't come to Earth before?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, thor

In the first Thor movie Odin explains that they rescued the earth from frost giants and then settled in Asgard and stopped venturing in other realms. At the time of war, Thor was too young to go to the war. So he didn't come to Earth.

But later Erik Selvig describes Thor as a hero of Norse Mythology. As per movie, the mythology was based on Odin's visit to world. So how could anyone include Thor in the mythology and so Erik know about Thor? I mean Thor didn't come to Earth, so how could Earth's people know him and make him a hero in mythology?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **[Thor (2011)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800369/)**, after Thor suggest going to [Jotunheim](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Jotunheim) (the home of the Frost Giants), **Fandral** and **Sif** speak out against it.

**Fandral says**:

> *This isn't like a journey to Earth, where you summon a little
>   lightning and thunder, the mortals worship you as a god.*

So it seems like Thor has "played" the *God of Thunder* on Earth at least once.

- **[Watch the scene on YouTube](https://youtu.be/uQYySb9fSHY?t=108)**

Answer (score 5):

I'd say it works, because Norse mythology isn't just based on stories that are said to have happened, but also on things that "will" happen.

Just like Ragnarök: Someone came up with the idea and described Thor in advance. But in addition, I think there's even one instance in the comics where Thor is implied to be a title rather than just being a name.

Comment: Even if  they come up with an idea,  how can they be so accurate? Were they so accurate to even introduce mjolnir?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing as such shown in MCU, but according to the Marvel storyline and stuff, Odin used to come to Earth very frequently due his addictions to alcohol and women.

He used to brag and spill secrets when drunk, either to men at a bar or to women whilst bedding them, and the news kept on spreading and so on.

I will add sources to my answer in an edit as soon as I find time for it.

Comment: Not to mention that parents have a tendency to talk about their children, so certainly Odin would have at least _mentioned_ Thor.

Comment: of course !their weaponry, their age,their powers, everything is to be bragged about ! right ?

Comment: ___["Responsibility, duty, honor. These are not merely virtues to which we must aspire. They are essential to every soldier and to every king."](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Odin)___ In the movies Odin didn't seem to be an irresponible drunk, at least not by the time Thor was old enough to wield Mjolnir.

Comment: I already said nothing to back up as far as MCU is considered, in other animes and stuff, Odin is always shown a pervert, you do the math !